# Highcharts series names in datalabel

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using highcharts library to output a column chart with 6 categories and 4 series.

I want to display the series name in the datalabel. Now it just gives the number.

[image: chart 1]

I've implemented a temporary solution but its not pretty:

[image: chart 2]

In the best solution, it would have O M G U above the category name, corresponding to the 4 columns per category.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `format` option to display series name as a data label, example:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                ...,
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                format: '{point.series.name}'
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8k5omy6z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.verticalAlign